Template Literal just turns into more string?
I'm learning JavaScript, absolute beginner here. I'm trying to get my first Template Literal to work. For example:
const firstName = "john"
const person1 = `He's &{firstName}`;

What I want to see when I log this to the console is
He's John
But what i get instead is
He's &{firstName}
How do I get the &{} to work within the backticks?

It's a dollar sign: ${...}  it's not an ampersand: &{...}. I would've preferred an & it makes more sense: && = AND and {...} = interpolation. When I see $ = jQuery.

@zer00ne oh ofc! Thank you. Yes, I agree, it would make more sense with an ampersand.
